# Creating and saving Visio 2013 Drawing(Vsdx file) using C#

Tags: c#, visio

I am writing a program that generates vsdx file, currently using the Microsoft.Interop.visio reference. My dev computer has visio on it, but the end user may or may not have installed. Will this tool fail if visio isn't installed on the end users computer, or is this interop service separate from the actual application?

Comment: Did you try to run it on the end user's computer? I am not an expert on `vsdx`, but it's the first step you should do.

Comment: yes i tried on client system where visio 2013 is not installed .Any API that can resolve my problem or any other way to save VSDX file from my application

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must need Visio installed on client machine. but if you are creating the visio from your code and want to save it on clients local machine then

```
 FileInfo file = "";// Your File 
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-visio.drawing.main+xml";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename= RateTemplate.vsdx");
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
```

this allows you to Open/Save the file on the Client's machine, if m/c got visio 2013, then you can even open the .vsdx file .